# FastReport - how to remove "prepared report" save option?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, fastreport

When I preview my report (TfrxReport component) I always have "prepared report" save option. Have can I remove it? Using C++ Builder XE7.

Comment: So you have a `prepared report` and you want to clear it?

Comment: @sami When I preview the report under "Save" that option is always there by default. I don't need it since I add my own exports (RTF,PDF etc.) and I want to remove that option.

Comment: You mean that you want to remove `Save` button ?

Comment: No. When you click the Save button the first option is "Prepared Report". That is what I want to remove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this steps :

- Go to `Preview Options` , then expend it.
- You will see `Buttons` , Expend it .
- Uncheck `pbSave`

Comment: Thanks Sami! You've been great help today!